# Conflito de regras no .htaccess

Tags: regex, htaccess, url-rewrite

Estou enfrentando um erro com o arquivo .htaccess e não estou conseguindo resolver, é o seguinte:

Possuo a seguinte regra:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Essa regra tem como objetivo ignorar a extensão .php de todos os arquivos acessados no meu diretório. No entanto, quando eu utilizo essa regra, as demais param de funcionar, como por exemplo, essas:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).$ cidade.php?slug_cidade=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^restrito/usuarios/pagina/([^/.]+)$ restrito/usuarios.php?pagina=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^restrito/edit/usuario/([^/.]+)$    restrito/edit/usuario.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Quando utilizo a regra para ignorar as extensões, todos os arquivos: `cidade.php`, `restrito/usuarios.php`, e `restrito/edit/usuario.php` ao serem acessados mostram Error `404`, quando eu removo a regra para ignorar as extensões, eles passam a funcionar normalmente, da forma que eu gostaria.

Alguma forma de resolver esse problema?

Comment: Alguma solução pessoal?

Answer (score 1):

Não vai funcionar, pois no ReWriteRule você está capturando tudo `^([^\.]+)$` até o  fim da linha e substituindo o grupo de captura por ele mesmo (`$1`) com a extensão ".php", logo quando você possui um arquivo de nome a.php você irá reescreve-lo como a.php.php, fazendo com que as outras regex parem de funcionar por conterem referencias invalidas.

Caso queira ignorar a extensão do arquivo, você deve utilizar `^([^\.]+)\..?$` isso vai capturar tudo até a ultima ocorrencia de ".", assim você pode ignorar a extensão e fazer a substituição por ".php" sem medo de quebrar o path